# chmod not working for file system on an external drive

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions

I tried to change permission on a number of files and folders with chmod. the command returned no error but the mode was not changed. Does anyone know why?

```
pls VideoA # ls -ld Movies/
drwx------ 1 alex alex 16777216 Jul 27 11:15 Movies/
pls VideoA # chmod -v 755 Movies/
mode of 'Movies/' changed from 0700 (rwx------) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
pls VideoA # ls -ld Movies/
drwx------ 1 alex alex 16777216 Jul 27 11:15 Movies/
pls VideoA # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

VideoA, VideoB, VideoC are 3 volumes on a USB external disk. when I run fdisk, it shows as follows:

```
pls alex # pwd
/media/alex
pls alex # ll
total 49160
drwxr-xr-x+ 5 root root 4096 Jul 27 18:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 26 19:31 ../
drwx------ 1 alex alex 16777216 Jul 27 18:54 VideoA/
drwx------ 1 alex alex 16777216 Dec 31 1969 VideoB/
drwx------ 1 alex alex 16777216 Dec 31 1969 VideoC/

pls alex # fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcbce2081

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1 256 651174143 651173888 310.5G f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb2 651174144 1302348031 651173888 310.5G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3 1302348032 1953522943 651174912 310.5G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb5 288 651174143 651173856 310.5G 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Another strange thing: /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb5 overlap. Any idea why is like that? did I do something wrong?

Comment: You can't set Linux's permissions on an "alien" filesystem. Neither NTFS and exFAT (that doesn't support permissions at all) supports Unix's permissions

Comment: Try changing the permissions configured for the mount itself.

Comment: @Alex: Tell that to ntfs-3g...

Comment: @Alex: Got it. But I think Linux should be able to operate on NTFS metadata, at least possible theoretically.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: that worked. cool! It saved me from reformating the disk.

Comment: @grawity Arghhh... I was to fast regarding NTFS :( Thx for refreshing my memory. AlexL, you right, Linux, or to be more precise,- ntfs-3g can manage Unix's permissions on NTFS. As about exFAT, my first statement is still correct